# Pass an object method an array of strings (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

The goal is to pass an array of strings (Substitute teacher names) to the 'pickSubstituteTeacher' method and return one random teacher. I cannot figure out how to send an array of strings to the object method and return the random value.

```
class School {
  constructor(name, level, numberOfStudents) {
    this._name = name;
    this._level = level;
    this._numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
  }

  static pickSubstituteTeacher(substituteTeachers) {
    let ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*substituteTeachers.length);
    return substituteTeachers[ranNum];
  }
}

const school1 = new School('school1', 'two', 233);


let randomTeacher = School.pickSubstituteTeacher['teacher1','teacher2','teacher3'];

console.log(randomTeacher);
```

Comment: well... i mean, an array looks like this: `['a','b','c']`.

Comment: sorta related - you've made `pickSubstitudeTeacher` a static method, so you should be calling it with `School.pickSubstituteTeacher` -- or did you mean to _not_ make it static?

Comment: I know, but even with square brackets it won't work.

Comment: @chazsolo  you're right. I should be using School.pickSubstituteTeacher. But I still don't know how to pass it an array and return the randomly generated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put parentheses around the array to indicate that the array is the argument to the method.

```
let randomTeacher = School.pickSubstituteTeacher(['teacher1','teacher2','teacher3']);
```

Comment: Case closed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are sooo close...

Go with this: `let randomTeacher = School.pickSubstituteTeacher(['teacher1', 'teacher2', 'teacher3']);`